# Instagram error "You can not like this media"?

Tags: ios, instagram

I am using instagram API for developing my app. In my app , I am allowing user to like others media. For this I am using following url with parameters like mediaId and accessToken.

"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/%@/likes?access_token=%@",mediaId,accessToken

Problem is Sometime I am getting error "You can't like this media".

If you have any solution then please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the user is not allowing non friends to like? It looks like a valid error and the issue is not something you will be able to solve. It just the instagram API telling you that the like action is not allowed on the given media.

Answer (score 2):

It happens when you try to like a media of a private profile, and the access_token (user) you are using to like does not have access to view that profile.

Comment: I am facing same issue , can you help me from where i can make that account public and make like that , because when i make like from ios sdk its given me same error with alert like error code 400 you can not like this media

Comment: we can like Any particular media from the instagram app but API Show error when try to send like from the code. show 400 error and msg: you can not like this media. do u have any idea about

Comment: does it happen when u are just liking that one media with same user, or does happen after u have liked a bunch of other photos and then it starts failing?

Comment: This is not a private or public error. Did you get likes before this issue? I mean other people who liked your pics with your Instagram client.